# Postgres ordering not working as expected

Tags: sql, postgresql

Below is the query i am using :

```
 SELECT T.abcd,
             String_agg(T.yyy, ',') AS yyys,
             T.bbb
      FROM   (SELECT s.abcd,
                     up.yyy,
                     s.bbb,
                     s.secondary_id
              FROM   A s
                     join B su
                       ON su.search_term_id = s.id
                     join lll_yyy up
                       ON up.lll = su.lll
              ORDER  BY s.abcd
                        su.page_no,
                        su.position) T GROUP  BY T.abcd, T.bbb
```

Basically the order of data produced after my aggregated function is not as expected .

The output should be sorted by abcd and page_no and position . 
Expected output:

```
A | 1,2,3,4 | XX
```

Actual Output

```
A |2,4,1,3 | XX
```

the second column in not sorted based on page_no,position as given in the query .

The abcd column has a wide variety of data with numbers,special chars 
etc. example: `0900 dr jne pink`, `0900 dr jne pink`,`098 lakhani shoe`, `iphone`, `c??mpu men shoe sport` are some sample terms in the `abcd` column

I tried using collate "C" option

Is there a way to figure out which word is screwing up the sort order

Comment: Example please.

Comment: When sorting strings, `'10'` will be lower then `'2'`. If you want to treat them as numbers see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/postgresql+natural-sort

Comment: If you want to get helpful answers, then please **[EDIT]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Comment: Have refactored by post . Please help

Comment: What order do you get you consider incorrect? Give an example of, say, five strings, the order you get and the order you want instead along with an explanation why you consider your order correct.

Comment: Added an example

Comment: There is at least a `)` missing. At least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the ORDER BY clause in the [aggregate expression:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#syntax-aggregates)

```
SELECT T.abcd,
         String_agg(T.yyy, ',' ORDER BY s.abcd, su.page_no, su.position) AS yyys,
         T.bbb
  FROM   (SELECT s.abcd,
                 up.yyy,
                 s.bbb,
                 s.secondary_id
          FROM   A s
                 join B su
                   ON su.search_term_id = s.id
                 join lll_yyy up
                   ON up.lll = su.lll) T GROUP  BY T.abcd, T.bbb
```

The ORDER BY clause in a derived table is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

You are showing an incomplete query. However, it seems to be like this:

```
SELECT ... FROM (SELECT ... ORDER  BY ...)
```

Your main select doesn't have an `ORDER BY` clause here. You can hence get the result rows in any order. The `ORDER BY` clause in the subquery can be ignored by the DBMS, because data in a table (which includes derived tables, i.e. subqueries) is considered an unordered set.